# How to properly clean html post to save in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, blogs, sanitization

I'm trying to create a blog system, I'm at a point where i want to save the blog post data into mysql but little confuse how to clean or sanitize the data here is what I've tried

```
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Now when i posted blog data through ajax it looked like

```
<h1 class="text-center">
    Write the titles of article here
</h1>
```

then i clean the post data & echo it

```
echo $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connecDB, test_input($_POST['page__title']));
```

Then here is what I got in response

```
\r\n    Write the titles of article here\r\n
```

I want to know why I'm getting these \r\n in the response how can i get rid of them which is the best way of cleaning html post

Note: i want to save the data as html in mysql

I already have a regex that will find style & script tags & remove it, i also tried removing strip slashes & tried adding strip_tags also but still I'm getting \r\n

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of stripslashes? Also, you have to also be careful with user displayed content. You want to make sure you HTML encode it. If you cannot do that (in this instance you're creating a blog), you need to at least strip things like <script></script> tags. ls it just me or are your params to mysqli_real_escape_string reversed?

Comment: @SoWeLie Yeah I already have a regex that will find style & script tags & remove it, i also tried removing strip slashes & tried adding strip_tags also but still I'm getting `\r\n `

Comment: Oh, wait. That makes sense actually, I think mysqli_real_escape_string would replace white space characters like \r\n with \\r\\n. Try replacing \\r and \\n with \r \n.

Comment: @SoWeLie it means that trim is not working on it, as i removed mysqli_real_escape_string & got this in response `Write the titlesss of article here` 5 spaces before Write

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used PHP. That is strange though, as the manual states that trim() should remove \r and \n.

Comment: it's working if i put trim below strip_tags! It's totally strange

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `\r\n` because `mysql_real_escape_string()` replaces control characters with the corresponding escape sequences. This function is only intended for use when you're going to substitute the variable into a MySQL query, it shouldn't be used for outputting in HTML. The proper function to sanitize for HTML output is `htmlentities()`.

```
$title = test_input($_POST['page__title']);
echo htmlentities($title);
```

If you want to retain line breaks in the output, you should also use `nl2br()`.

```
echo nl2br(htmlentities($title));
```